# Not returning right sum in sql where ID column in table 1 is created through view

Tags: sqlite

I have a large database where table 1 and table 2 are connected BY id and I am not able to do sum of score.

table 1

```
code  id
1      12345
1      67533
2      87654
3      65432
```

table2

```
id      score
12345   60
67533   50
87654   32
65432   67
87654   45
```

output

```
code     id        score 
 1      12345      60
 1      67533      50
 2      87654      77
 3      65432      67
```

I used the following code:

```
SELECT
t1.code,t1.id,p.score
from
(select t2.id,
sum(t2.score)
from
table t2
group by
id) as p
from
table t1
groupby
t1.code,t1.id,p.score
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, assuming your tables are named `table1` and `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.id, sum(t2.score)
    from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    group by t2.id
    order by code;
```

See a [demonstration over at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e13477/10)

Comment: My column id in table t1 is stored as view. So i dont know how to join two tables when one of column is in view

Comment: Have you tried the query? Please edit your question to include the results of the queries you've tried and also include all relevant information so that people answering can give the most appropriate answer.